# How to resume review process after updating pull request at GitHub?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I forked GitHub repository and created pull request. Reviewer requested changes from me:

[image: Github changes requested]

> Changes requested
> 1 review requesting changes by reviewers with write access. [Learn more.](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-request-reviews)

I've committed and pushed necessary changes in pull request branch, so they are displaying at pull request page. Now I want ask contributor to continue review my changes.

Is there any button or action for this? Can't find this.

[image: Buttons]

Answer (score 61):

2 years and a half years later, (February 2019), do check if **[the new button "Re-request review"](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-02-21-re-request-review-on-a-pull-request/)** would help.

As [illustrated on twitter](https://twitter.com/github/status/1098688981598842880/photo/1), if your PR was already reviewed, but now it’s time for round 2: With fresh eyes and fresh code, re-request a review

[image: Re-Request a review]

---

Note/caveat: (from "[**Requesting a pull request review**](https://help.github.com/en/articles/requesting-a-pull-request-review)")

> Pull request authors can't request reviews unless they are either a repository owner or collaborator with write access to the repository.

As noted [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893008/how-to-resume-review-process-after-updating-pull-request-at-github/54817351#comment98201411_54817351) by [gertvdijk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1254292/gertvdijk):

> I am a *contributor* on the project and the owner of the PR.
>   It does not make sense to me that I need to be a collaborator on the project to request a re-review?
>
> Oh, wow, it's by design that PR authors can't use this feature?
>   Damn, that's very much killing the whole feature.

Comment: I don't have that button. Any specific permission you need on a project to do this? It's really problematic on GH that for PRs I handled the review comments, the status remains "Changes requested" with no power for me to change that. Commenting does not always help and the PR keeps being listed like that in all listings/reports. :-(

Comment: @gertvdijk Check if you are a collaborator in that project.

Comment: I am a *contributor* on the project and the owner of the PR. It does not make sense to me that I need to be a *collaborator* on the project to request a re-review? (FTR, it's about [this PR](https://github.com/PowerDNS/pdns/pull/7645)).

Comment: Oh, wow, it's by design that PR authors can't use this feature? Damn, that's very much killing the whole feature. *"Pull request authors can't request reviews unless they are either a repository owner or collaborator with write access to the repository."* ([source](https://help.github.com/en/articles/requesting-a-pull-request-review))

Comment: @gertvdijk I agree. And I have included your comment in the answer to make that constraint more visible.

Answer (score 28):

I agree with @prabodhprakash, use the Gear next to "Reviewers" to reselect the reviewer. This changes his status from the red 'x' back to the orange circle.

The problem is the status of the PR remains as "Changes requested". There should be a state after this such as "Changes resolved" or "Needs review" again that is initiated by the requestor, via a button, when s/he is ready for the PR to be looked at again. Otherwise, the PR still looks like it's in the already-reviewed-and-rejected" state.

Answer (score 13):

The solution is to [dismiss the review](https://help.github.com/en/articles/dismissing-a-pull-request-review). You can confidently do this because the original conversation will still be present, and you'll be asked for a comment for you to explain why you're doing this.

In a nutshell, look for the drop-down arrow next to the "1 change requested". From there you'll be able to "re-request review", but note that this alone won't change the state. In addition, or instead, you'll have to choose "dismiss review" and enter a comment, such as "made the requested changes". After you confirm, your pull request should show again as "review required" on the list of PRs, so the ball will no longer be in your court.

Comment: If you force push the requested change disappears, and you can't dismiss the review any more.

Comment: For anyone else who marked a bunch of individual changes complete, and requested re-review, THIS was the answer that actually un-stuck a PR for me

Answer (score 6):

The reviewer gets removed from the actual list (even though he is listed there with a cross), he does not even see the pull request in his tasks anymore. Just add him as a reviewer again.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way you can intimate user about it.

> You can comment that you have made changes - this comment will
>   give him a notification.

Other than that, if possible, notify him via some other medium.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just wait if the reviewer is watching the issue or write a comment that you did the requested change (I would do the latter). Then the reviewer can have another look and approve the PR.

Answer (score 0):

Without the reviewer who raised the request for changes, not possible to merge especially in corporate accounts when you can't dismiss the comments/ review requests even if others `approve` your pull request as attached. You can see other person approved but one person requested changes and even when it was addressed and `marked resolved`, that person need to approve who asked changes. This can create issues because the person may not be available or even no more working for the company.

Best way:

```
Step 1 : Cancel pull request and make sure branch is not deleted.
Step 2 : Create a new pull request from the same branch and request review.
```

[image]

[image]